# Difference between $new_array = array() and $new_array = []

Tags: php

What's the difference between

```
$new_array = array()
```

and

```
$new_array = []
```

I know they are both used to declare new array, but it seems like `$new_array = []` echoes or does something different which breaks my web app which is using JavaScript and XHR requests (from a totally different function).

Comment: no. it doesnt. the latter is just the equivalent shorthand introduced in PHP 5.4. If that echo'es something or breaks your app, your are likely not running on 5.4

Comment: Maybe your server uses an older PHP version (http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php).

Comment: are you using a version of php earlier than 5.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` is only supported since PHP 5.4, otherwise it causes a syntax error and your code will not be executed at all.

In PHP5.4+ there is no difference.